# How to delay component instantiation until data from service is received in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component

I have a service wich fetches data from server with its `get` method:

```
export class UserService implements IRestService<User> {
    constructor(public http: Http) {
    }

    get(): Rx.Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get('api/ui_user', <any> {
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
            })
            .toRx()
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

And I have a component which uses this service.

```
constructor(emplService: EmployeesService, userService: UserService){
    this.emplService = emplService;
    this.isDisplayMenu = false;
    this.user = new User();

    userService.get()
        .subscribe(usr => {
            this.user = usr;
        });
}
```

Because data is fetched asyncronously, the component is instantiated and rendered, and only after that data is received. View gets populated with data and looks good eventually but at first I have an error in console:

```
GET data:image/png;base64,undefined net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

It happens in my view:

```
 <img class="user-avatar" [src]="'data:image/png;base64,' + user.avatar">
```

I want the component to wait until data is received before it rendered itself. Is this possible? I was thinking about [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) but documentation is so poor I can't understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use the [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgIf-directive.html) directive.

Something like...

```
<img *ngIf="user.avatar" class="user-avatar" [src]="'data:image/png;base64,' + user.avatar">
```

Then the element won't then be rendered in the page until the `user.avatar` is truthy.

Comment: You can also use the `ngSrc` directive.

Comment: @georgeawg you sure you aren't talking about angular 1?

Comment: Although, it doesn't adress my question directly but it solved my problem.

Comment: does not delay instantiation and does not work if the component contains a router

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is correct but there is another option.
To delay your component to be loaded until some service is resolved then you can use [Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

Here is some [good blog post](https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267) that describes implementing one.

Basically Component that has resolver specified doesn't load until promise/observable inside resolver is resolved.

Comment: Isn't usage of resolvers limited to components that get created by router for a certain route? Or you can use resolvers with any component?

Comment: @dKab Yes you have to specify a resolver inside your router. I assumed you load your component this way. Then you should use *ngIf as mentioned above. You could also try using user?.avatar. This might work aswell.